# Rest Api service for shipping information Post -

Tags: api, shipping, rest-api, magento-2.0.2

V1/carts/mine/shipping-information for this service which parameter are required.. 
I had given below parameters

```
{
  "addressInformation": {
    "shippingAddress": {
      "id": 0,
      "region": "string",
      "regionId": 0,
      "regionCode": "string",
      "countryId": "IN",
      "street": [
        "Lane5 pune"
      ],
      "company": "string",
      "telephone": "9494949494",
      "fax": "string",
      "postcode": "411001",
      "city": "pune",
      "firstname": "vaibhav",
      "lastname": "kapoor",
      "middlename": "string",
      "prefix": "string",
      "suffix": "string",
      "vatId": "string",
      "customerId": 2,
      "email": "vaibhav@gmail.com",
      "sameAsBilling": 0,
      "customerAddressId": 0,
      "saveInAddressBook": 0,
      "extensionAttributes": {},
      "customAttributes": [
        {
          "attributeCode": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "billingAddress": {
      "id": 0,
      "region": "string",
      "regionId": 0,
      "regionCode": "string",
      "countryId": "IN",
      "street": [
        "Lane5 une"
      ],
      "company": "string",
      "telephone": "9494949494",
      "fax": "string",
      "postcode": "411001",
      "city": "pune",
      "firstname": "vaibhav",
      "lastname": "kapoor",
      "middlename": "string",
      "prefix": "string",
      "suffix": "string",
      "vatId": "string",
      "customerId": 2,
      "email": "vaibhav@gmail.com",
      "sameAsBilling": 0,
      "customerAddressId": 0,
      "saveInAddressBook": 0,
      "extensionAttributes": {},
      "customAttributes": [
        {
          "attributeCode": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "shippingMethodCode": "freeshipping",
    "shippingCarrierCode": "freeshipping",
    "extensionAttributes": {},
    "customAttributes": [
      {
        "attributeCode": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Error message is:

```
"message": "Unable to save shipping information. Please, check input data."
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below?

```
    {
    "addressInformation": {
        "shipping_address": {
            "firstname": "Your name",
            "lastname": "your last name",
            "city": "India",
            "country_id": "IN",
            "region": "Region",
            "postcode": "123456",
            "telephone": "1234567",
            "region_id": 0,
            "street": ["Line1", "Line2"],
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_address_id": 1
        },
        "billing_address": {
            "firstname": "Your name",
            "lastname": "your last name",
            "city": "India",
            "country_id": "IN",
            "region": "Region",
            "postcode": "123456",
            "telephone": "1234567",
            "region_id": 0,
            "street": ["Line1", "Line2"],
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_address_id": 1
        },
        "shipping_method_code": "freeshipping",
        "shipping_carrier_code": "freeshipping"
    }
}
```

Make sure the

```
"shippingMethodCode": "freeshipping",
"shippingCarrierCode": "freeshipping",
```

are the code(s) available when you retrieve using the shipping methods API:
http://magento2_path/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-methods

Hope this helps.

Joemar